# Create e-commerce website with or without CMS

Tags: web-development, cms, ecommerce

I have almost done the development of a software and I am now wondering about the distribution.

I will sell the software with monthly subscription and I will also sell other products related to the area of the software.

I need to create an e-commerce website with shopping basket, payment module, user roles, and everything to handle users and products.

So I don't know if I need to use a CMS like WordPress, Prestashop or anyone else.

Until now, I have never thought about using a CMS because I can create website myself. But the website will have banking information, so it need to be secure and safe.

What is the best way to do such a website. Which CMS do you recommend if you recommend to use a CMS.

I don't have problem with learning new way to do something, new technologies or in this case learning courses about web security, on the contrary, I really appreciate it so if I can do an e-commerce website by myself learning some stuff it's with pleasure.

Comment: Did you try osCommerce?

Answer (score 0):

Opensource content management systems like drupal, wordpress, etc. have modules for ecommerce which can probably be used for your purposes i.e. selling downloadable software, selling physical products etc.

The payment modules will redirect you to the payment provider's site. Hence your site will not be keeping sensitive information.

So I suggest using a CMS that you are familiar with, based on your requirements. My own personal experience has been with [drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), drupal ubercart, and their associated modules.

The alternative is another system [Opencart](https://www.opencart.com)

But pick based on your overall requirements, and compare the various approaches first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I have posted this question, I have worked a lot on my project and nowadays I am going with a self made solution. CMS are not enough compatibles with my needs.